# Url schema for launching Google maps throwing Warning in iOS 9 and also not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, ios9, url-scheme

Following code was working fine with iOS 8.4 and earlier, but from iOS 9.0 it starts throwing warning as well giving `false` always.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://"]]
```

It is throwing warning as:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme comgooglemaps-x-callback"
```

Do anyone having any idea about, why it is failing in iOS 9 and why throwing error as `This app is not allowed to query for scheme comgooglemaps-x-callback`, is there any permissions required to query it?

**EDIT**

I have added following items in my info.plist, but it is still having same problem.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps-x-callback</string>
</array>
```

Comment: have you added LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in plist?

Comment: add this in plist <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array><string>comgooglemaps</string>
    </array>

Comment: still giving same error

Comment: please check the edited question

Comment: Its an issue  read this discussion: https://github.com/googlemaps/OpenInGoogleMaps-iOS/issues/3

Comment: Yes, i checked this, but dont know it is not working still

Comment: Try with this https://github.com/googlemaps/OpenInGoogleMaps-iOS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add a LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry to your Info.plist and list the schemes that you want your app to query.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
     <string>urlscheme</string>
     <string>urlscheme2</string>
     <string>urlscheme3</string>
     <string>urlscheme4</string>
</array>
```

see http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl.html (also contains a Link to the corresponding WWDC15-Session-Video)

Comment: After adding this it is still giving the same error

Comment: Please check the edited question, it is still giving me same problem